# VB.net For loop wrong i

Tags: vb.net

I don't know what or why it is happening. In the code below at the first run i = 0. Working fine. At the end i = 2. Also fine. But then, for some reason that I can't comprehend, suddenly i = 3. This gives an System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, which I understand, since there are only 4 items in the list.

How does change i from 2 to 3?

```
noOfSpeedLimiterPositions = speedLimiterPositions.count() '= 4
    
For i = 0 To noOfSpeedLimiterPositions - 1
    speedLimiterPosition = speedLimiterPositions(i)
    nextSection = speedLimiterPosition + speedLimiterPositions(i + 1) 'exception thrown here
        
    While speedLimiterPosition < nextSection
        rollerSpeedLimiterPositions.add(speedLimiterPosition)
        speedLimiterPosition = speedLimiterPosition + 57.5 * 2
    End While
    MessageBox.Show(i) 'shows 0
    i = i + 2
    MessageBox.Show(i) 'shows 2
Next
```

Comment: What's the value of `noOfSpeedLimiterPositions`?

Comment: I'm quite proficient with VB.NET, but even I don't know exactly what happens if you change the value of a loop variable in the middle of a loop. Better not do that, it leads to code that's hard to understand (as you have seen). If you want other increments than 1, use `For ... To ... Step ...` instead.

Comment: @Heinzi, that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned above I now use step:

```
noOfSpeedLimiterPositions = speedLimiterPositions.count()
    
For i = 0 To noOfSpeedLimiterPositions - 1 Step 2
    speedLimiterPosition = speedLimiterPositions(i)
    nextSection = speedLimiterPosition + speedLimiterPositions(i + 1)
        
    While speedLimiterPosition < nextSection
        rollerSpeedLimiterPositions.add(speedLimiterPosition)
        speedLimiterPosition = speedLimiterPosition + 57.5 * 2
    End While
Next
```

Comment: This is because you have an even number of items in the collection (as shown in the question). What happens if you have an odd number of items? i.e., `speedLimiterPositions.Count()` is `5` instead of `4`.